# How to display image with axes using Simulink?

Tags: matlab, plot, simulink

I want to display image with axes labelled with `XData` and `YData` as it possible with `imshow`.

My simulation generates new image each step.

I found no way to do this neither with [Video Viewer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/videoviewer.html?searchHighlight=Matrix%20Viewer) nor with [Matrix Viewer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/matrixviewer.html?searchHighlight=Matrix%20Viewer).

May it is possible to hook them somehow?

Comment: is it not possible to use standard matlab-commands, like creating a figure and axes and then using imshow?

Comment: Yes, but would like to find conventional solution...

Comment: Is it just the axes labelling that doesn't work with the Video Viewer? You can maybe try the To Video Display block if you're on Windows, but I suspect you won't be able to label the axes either. The only way I can think of to do what you want would be to use a MATLAB Function block with some MATLAB code, as already suggested. You may want to run this at a lower sample rate than the model not to slow down the execution time too much.